# query-replace-read-to: Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, replace, query-replace

I want to rename file in `dired` by replacing underscores with spaces. I hit 
<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd> (`dired-do-rename`) and after typing <kbd>M-%</kbd> (`query-replace`) I got:

```
query-replace-read-to: Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer
```

Is it possible to makes replaces in minibufer?

Is [Recursive Edit](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recursive-Edit.html) here?

**UPDATE** I recall <kbd>% r</kbd> `dired-do-rename-regexp` but I ask about replacing in minibufer. Please do not count this workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do. But if you want to use `M-%` in the active minibuffer then yes, you need to first set `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to non-`nil`. By default, the value of that variable is `nil`, which prevents you being prompted for another command when you are already being prompted for a different command.

But please explain what you are *really* trying to do. I'm guessing there is an easier and more straightforward way to do it, whatever it is.

Comment: `enable-recursive-minibuffers` is commented in my `.emacs` 4 years ago. Seems I found it complicated. Setting to `t` allow me to perform desired tasks. Thanks!

Comment: You can also, instead of setting `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to `t`, `let`-bind it to `t` in your own command, which calls `query-replace`. That way, it affects only query-replacing.